# How to make Stub using Stub(class, closure) using Spock

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, stubbing

I want to write spock test using Stub I have a class Site with two methods

```
    getText()
    getTitle()
```

So I write

```
MyTestClass{

Site site

def "test()"{
    site = Stub(Site){
                getText()<<"text"
                getTitle()<<"title"}
...
}
}
```

And the error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
com.example.MyTestClass.getText() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Why Spock thinks that the **getText**() is part of **MyTestClass**, but not from **Site**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the arrows the other way, e.g. `getText() >> "text"` :)

Comment: OMG I spent 1 hour for searching for similar problems. And I gave up.
Thanks, @Gregor Petrin